# ms365 power automate online: how to get xml attribute values for a particular text value

Tags: power-automate

I am looking to extract only the wow:rank values at which the text in between the > and < starts with BOOM-. I was able to get the text values in between the > and < that start with BOOM- using filters in power automate 365 online, but i just couldn't simultaneously get the wow:rank attribute values. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<category wow:rank="0">EIGEGenderEquality</category>
<category wow:rank="9" >BOOM-A0304-DiscriminatoryPracticesOnTheBasisOfSex</category>
<category wow:rank="0">EIGEGenderEquality</category>
<category wow:rank="5" url = "www.google.ca">BOOM-EIGEGenderEquality</category>
```

Have a great day! :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the PowerAutomate `xpath` expression (coupled with `xml`) doesn't handle the extraction of attributes.  It merely provides the ability to filter on all elements based on the given xquery expression provided.

In that case, you can use the below expression on each element within your XML to get your result ...

```
replace(split(split(variables('XML String'), 'wow:rank="')[1], '"')[0], '"', '')
```

... that was applied in the `Initialize wow:rank` step below.

[image: Flow]

Outside of that, you could make it a lot more complex by making an API call to a service that does it for you but it's potentially a lot more work and not really worth it.

If your scenario was more complex, then I'd look into doing that.

Comment: Thanks so much! Do you know if there are APIs that can do this? By API do you mean function calls outside of Power Automate?

Comment: I haven’t looked but I suspect you’d need to write your own. If you’ve accepted my answer then can you please flag it as so? It rewards those who help.

Comment: Actually, I only just realized that your last element has an additional attribute, my answer won’t work for that so I need to update it. Will do that and let you know.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: How do I go about accepting your reply? I cannot find the button

Answer (score 0):

You can get to attributes easily by using the `@` symbol, like `@wow:rank`.

In a "Apply to each", you would use:

```
xpath(xml(item()), 'string(/category/@wow:rank)')
```

to loop through each of them.